# Rendering animation is not working

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I only have an animation of 5 seconds and is only rending like less than 1 second,  the worst is rendering stuff that is not there, I don't understand why.

In the first image is how is supposed to be, and the second pic is how it render.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Comment: please provide your blend file - so we can definitely help you. Everything else if often just guessing what it could be...because there are several reasons possible.

Comment: thank you. i added an answer which helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this (your "empty")

[image]

This won't be rendered.

If you want to render an image do this:

1. add plane
2. resize it and move it as you want it (basically give it the size and the position of your "empty")
3. give it this shader

[image]

then you will get:

[image]

Comment: But i don't want to render with the image. that was just for reference and that flower in blue i don´t know why is there, i deleted. the end result should be like the first image on my post. i still don't know why is that flower appearing :(((